# Asp.Net Core, Loading partial view in to a form and trying to get not the list of the model on form submit

Tags: asp.net-core

Asp.Net Core, Loading partial view into a form and trying to get not the list of the model on form submit,

So i have a with some rows of data. i have a button add to the from so if you need more lines which is currently been loading in my ajax. but im not able to get the infomation from the feilds loading in the form from the ajax append.

Comment: Things would go better if you post your code.

Comment: I don't really have code for it. I'm not sure how I should approach it.

Comment: @Nelles I solved it myself. thanks, anyways